# Troubleshooting issues with third party mouse?

Tags: macos, mac

I'm having trouble using third party wireless mice with Sierra.

I've tried 2, and they both have a lot of issues - they are very laggy and generally hard to use. Both work fine with Windows.

These haven't been helpful:

- modifying the tracking speed in the mouse settings
- USB Overdrive
- disabling the mouse acceleration with: defaults write .GlobalPreferences com.apple.mouse.scaling -1

Any suggestions for other things to try?

Comment: Make and models of the mice?  Bluetooth?

Comment: @Allan they are both usb wireless. Countor Unimouse and Anker Vertical mouse https://www.amazon.com/Unimouse-wireless-technology-programmable-Right-hand/dp/B075VBGNZ3 https://www.amazon.com/Anker-Wireless-Vertical-Ergonomic-Optical/dp/B00BIFNTMC

Comment: Add that info to your original question!

Comment: Sounds like radio interference with wireless.  Try (as a test) disabling your WiFi (turn it off) and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: @Allan the problems continue when I disable my Wifi, but there are a lot of other people in my office using Wifi?

Comment: Two things I would try:  1)  try a wired mouse.  If the lagging goes away, it has to do with the connection between the mouse and receiver.  If not, it's an issue with the MacBook (hardware/software).  2)  Take it outside/home.  If the problem goes away, it has to do with interference at your job.